# Does this multiple-choice question make sense?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Last night, my son came across the following question while doing his homework:

He acquired a lot of debts at.......
a. play
b. prose
c. novel
d. poem

He asked me about the meaning of the question. Unfortunately, l couldn't answer him. I looked up all the entries in the question in a number of dictionaries, but it seems that the meaning is vague. I think the whole question doesn't make sense, does it?

Comment: Yes, this question makes sense.  What exactly is vague for you?

Comment: What is vague to me is the connection in meaning between (acquired ...debts ) and the rest of the sentence.

Comment: The meaning is that he made a lot of debts and owns a lot of money now because he was involved in or was doing something (a, b,c or d).

Comment: This type of made-up sentence is probably inappropriate for a child.

Answer (score 1):

I think whoever made the test question is being a little cute. All four answers are types of the written word. But one doesn't usually associate writing with acquiring debts. Unless the writing you are doing is keeping score in a poker game at which you are at play--and losing, or filling out the racing form at the track where you are at play--and losing.

The question is a little awkward, but if it was written by your son's teacher, it's a good sign. He or she is trying to make the test interesting and putting in a little extra effort for the kids just because.

Teacher gets an apple.

Comment: I'm wondering if the teacher used "acquired" in the sense of "had" here.

Comment: I think you are being very kind to the teacher. Such reasoning is too abstruse and speculative to be fitted to a child.

Comment: I think it is punning on two senses of the word _play_, and nothing to do with writing. The debts are presumably gambling debts from playing cards, but the multiple-choice answers interpret _play_ in the sense of a literary work.

Comment: @Kate Bunting: As a native speaker, how can you edit the question to sound more reasonable for the reader and easier enough for the child?

Comment: It's difficult, because I don't know what aspect of English the question was intended to test. The use of _play_ to mean gambling on card games seems rather old-fashioned to me.

Comment: @MidoMido It's janky from another angle, too. It doesn't sound natural at all to say someone acquired a lot of debts. Moreover, they wouldn't acquire them "at" something, you'd say "from" something--from gambling, for example. Is the teacher a native speaker?

Comment: @CWill: You're right. By the way, the teacher is not a native speaker and that's why l posted the question.